# Can we set the value of a control from variable

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, controls

Is it possible to set the value of a control whose control id is saved in a variable. The code looks like

```
var textmonth = $(this).parent().find('input[id$=txtmonths]').attr("id");
```

I'm trying to do something like this

```
textmonth.val("Only numbers");
```

Is it  really possible?

The demo code is given below:

The html code is:

```
<div id="pagecontent">
<h1>
        Collection Master</h1>

    <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="2" style="padding-left:40px; font-size:medium; padding-right:20px"
        width="100%" border="0">
        <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="width: 100%">
                    <asp:GridView ID="grdFees" runat="server" AllowPaging="false" CssClass="Grid" AutoGenerateColumns="false"><Columns>

                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SI NO" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center"
                                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" ItemStyle-Width="3%">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1%>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Sub Category" DataField="SUB_CAT" ItemStyle-CssClass="subcat" ItemStyle-Width="15%"
                                HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Fees Paid (Months,Quarters)" DataField="PAID_FEES" ItemStyle-Width="15%"
                                HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Pending Fees" DataField="PEND_FEES" ItemStyle-Width="5%"
                                HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" />
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Current Payment" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center"
                                ItemStyle-Width="10%">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtmonths" Width="80%" runat="server" 
                                     CssClass="Textbox"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <a href="#" class="openModalLink">
                                        <img style="vertical-align: middle; border: none" width="9%" alt="" 
                                        src="../Images/ico_map.gif"  id="imgmap" class="zoom"/></a>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </td>
            </tr>
</table>
    <div id="overlay" class="web_dialog_overlay">
        </div>
        <div id="dialog" class="web_dialog">
            <table style="width: 100%; border: 0px;" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td class="web_dialog_title" style="height: 16px">
                        Month Chooser</td>
                        <td class="web_dialog_title align_right" style="height: 16px">
                        <a href="#" id="btnClose">Close</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                <asp:GridView ID="grdpopup" runat="server" TabIndex="5">
                        <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center"
                                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" ItemStyle-Width="2%">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkselect" runat="server" CssClass="checkbox" 
                                    Width="15px" Checked="false" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Term" DataField="TERM" ItemStyle-Width="35%" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-CssClass="term" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Fee Amt." DataField="FEE_AMT" ItemStyle-Width="35%" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" ItemStyle-CssClass="feeamt" />

                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </td></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle">
                        <input id="btnSubmit1" type="button" value="Submit" class="button" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                </div>

</div>
```

The JS code is

```
<script src="../Jquery Autocomplete/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"> 
</script>
<script src="../Jquery Autocomplete/jquery.json-2.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"> 
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
    {
        var textmonth;
        var textamount;

        $(".openModalLink").click(function()
        {
            textmonth = $(this).parent().find('input[id$=txtmonths]').attr("id");
            textamount = $(this).parent().parent().find('input[id$=txtAmount]').attr("id");
            ShowDialog();
        });
        $("#btnClose").click(function(e) 
        {
            textmonth = null;
            textamount = null;
            HideDialog();
        });
        $('#btnSubmit1').click(function(e) 
        {
            var month = null;
            var amount = 0;
            $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i) 
            {

                var amt=$(this).closest("tr").find(".feeamt").text();
                if(amt != '')
                {
                    amount = amount + parseInt(amt,10);
                    if(month == null)
                    {
                        month = $(this).closest("tr").find(".term").text();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        month = month + ',' + $(this).closest("tr").find(".term").text();
                    }
                }
            });
            $("#"+textamount).val(amount);
            $("#"+textmonth).val(month);
            HideDialog();
        });
    });
    function ShowDialog(modal)
    {
        $("#overlay").show();
        $("#dialog").fadeIn(300);
        if (modal) {
            $("#overlay").unbind("click");
        }
    }
    function HideDialog() 
    {
        $("#overlay").hide();
        $("#dialog").fadeOut(300);

    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Are you actually trying to set the control?  Or do you mean to say you want to add a validation constraint?  (Both are very possible, but the syntax is different)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First the Get the Element ID
2. Then Use That ID With Jquery Selector by concating the ID Selector

   ```
   var textmonth = $(this).parent().find('input[id$=txtmonths]').attr("id");

   $('#'+ textmonth).val('your value');
   ```

Comment: You're selecting the `id` just to select the element by it... Doesn't make too much sense to me. You had the element allready!

Comment: @gdoron as OP said, he need a variable /object of it.  so that he can use with that. rather assigning directly

Comment: I don't know, it still doesn't make sense. just store the element you got, why do you save just the id then selecting it again?

Comment: thanks for the help....i'm using this variable to set the value of the control at a different part of the code

Comment: @gdoron ya i know. but as OP need variable for future use.  but your solution is more elegant than mine :)

Comment: @Prince. But why can't you save the element itself? can you elaborate some more about what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @gdoron sure gd...

initially i'm loading a popup when user clicks a "Popup" link in the grid. This popup has a list of months which the user needs to choose in order to make a payment. Once the user clicks the submit button in the popup, the selected months are loaded to a textbox in the gridview. 
The months should be updated only in the textbox in the same row as the "Popup" link.
User has to do the same for all the rows in the grid

Comment: @Prince. I still can't understand why do you store the id instead of the element.

Comment: @gdoron if i store the element i.e txtmonths, then the submit button will update all the textboxes in the grid. The textbox (txtmonths) is placed in an Item Template field.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this).parent().find('input[id$=' + txtmonths +']').val('foo');
```

where `txtmonths` is the end of the desired `id`.

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LNput/)

Comment: this one will update all the text boxes in the grid but I want to update only the text box in a particular row. Sorry for not explaining the entire procedure in the question

Comment: @Prince. I'm sure there is a better way of doing what you want than the accepted answer. Can you give me a DEMO to work with at http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: @Prince. Try this: `$(this).parent().find('input[id$=' + txtmonths +']').first().val('foo');`

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a selector and get the element by it:

```
var textmonth = $('#'+$(this).parent().find('input[id$=txtmonths]').attr("id"));
```

Comment: You're selecting the `id` just to select the element by it... Doesn't make too much sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
var textmonth = $(this).parent().find('input[id$=txtmonths]')
 remove .attr("id")
```

then you can use

```
textmonth.val("only numbers")
```